# Automate the Boring Stuff With Python Practice Project: collatz sequence Unknown loop?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

The outline:
Write a function named collatz() that has one parameter named number. If the number is even, then collatz() should print number // 2 and return this value. If the number is odd, then collatz() should print and return 3 * number + 1. Then write a program that lets the user type in an integer and that keeps calling collatz() on that number until the function returns the value 1.

my code:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2
    
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        result = 3 * number + 1
        print(result)
        return result
    
n = input("Give me a number")
while n != 1:
    collatz(int(n))
```

the output keeps infinitely printing the n value, and I can't figure out why. Please enlighten me

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should update the value of `n`:

```
while n != 1:
    n = collatz(int(n))
```

Otherwise, your loop has no progression, hence the infinite loop.

**Edit:** *Here's an explanation as to why this is necessary.*

Think about it logically. If you enter the body of the loop, then `n` must not be equal to 1. The loop continues to execute until `n` becomes 1. The only way for this to happen is for you to change (i.e. update) `n` so that it eventually reaches 1 and the loop can terminate.